# What happens to FileSystem.uploadAsync's promise when the app is brought back up again?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, file-transfer

According to [FileSystem.FileSystemSessionType](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemfilesystemsessiontype), when doing [FileSystem.uploadAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options) the method will return a promise.  Do promises still or get executed when resuming a react-native application?

Also it says it continues retrying until canceled, but I can't [FileSystem.uploadAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemuploadasyncurl-fileuri-options) returns a `Promise` and not something that allows cancellation. *I think I may ask this part as another question*